# How do I suppress the warnings about me using px in a layout xml?

Tags: android, android-lint, sony-smartwatch

I am working with a project that includes a `Sony SmartWatch` and when I send layouts to that I need to use real pixel values. [If you haven't used on its a watch that is connected via bluetooth and works as an extra display the "controlling" device can draw to]

I am using Eclipse so it gives me a warning that I should not use `px` in a `layout.xml` file ... is there a way to suppress these warnings for the lines where I know I should use `px`? (note: I want to suppress these warnings only on the lines where I know it should be used, so turning of this check from the lint error checker is not what I want)

And again, *I know that px is generally a bad idea when working with android, but this is one of the few cases where it is needed.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your xml, then you can disable the px-warnings by including this in your view: `tools:ignore="PxUsage"`.

This can be done automatically from the lint-warnings window by clicking on the "Suppress this error with an annotation/attribute" button.

Comment: Similarly, for anyone else wondering, you can ignore warnings for using dp in android:textSize with tools:ignore="spUsage".